# How to export mails from Lotus Notes into another mail client?

Tags: email, thunderbird, lotus-notes

Is there a way to export all mails from Lotus Notes (version 8.5) into a more useable mail client like Thunderbird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Lotus Notes cient is connected to a Lotus Domino server, then you can ask your server administrators (and/or help desk staff) whether the server's support for IMAP has been enabled. If it has, then you can simply use Thunderbird to access the server, and your messages will all** be there. And that's really what you want, isn't it? Not just a one-time export, but the ability to use an alternate mail client.

** Well, maybe not all. It's possible that your server has been set up to delete or archive messages after a period of time, and the client has been set up to not replicate the deletions.

Comment: thx that's what I need